# how to build this landing page using ListView

Tags: python, html, django

So basiclly i am trying to build a landing page that looks somthing like Netflix. i want to represent my Movie object's that are based on a Movie model. so these object's will apear in the ListView page.
i can't really understand how to inject using template coding and how to make it apear as blocks.

i am aiming for somthing like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssp8s.jpg)

my models.py :

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    '''

    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250,unique = True)
    director = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='movies_pictures', blank =True)
    length = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    copies = models.IntegerField()
    trailer = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        ''' this will reverse you back to movie detail page '''
        return reverse("movie_detail",kwargs={"pk":self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

i want to understand how to build the html page using the django template injections.

thank you from a head!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a movie queryset to your template when rendering.

```py
def movies(request):
    all_movies = Movies.objects.all() #or .filter(name__icontains="alien")
    context = {"movies": all_movies}
    return render(request, "movies/movie_list.html", context) # assumes you have created the template
```

Then you can use the Django template engine to loop through the movies and create the html/css that will get your movies to look however you want

```py
{% for movie in movies %}
    <div>{{ movie.name}}</div>
    <div>{{ movie.director}}</div>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Once you've got a handle on function based views and passing data to the template, have a look at [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/)

Comment: ok i got it using class based views